# How to create this Regex for Python?

Tags: python, regex, linux

I wanna extract only specific text in a content per line. For example, I have a file with many text like the following:

```
USEEER1:$product$*2*6000*222*bba98bfcb2b21dddde5d0656fc9221a0494b4fe70745107211e52*1b2a942fe069da12a226e3532dbc*c99c46a2c81b4c05cb3137ab30382394*31e7b8f7014160915ca98ce852e112e0123e6adc65ca4f083*4a722d4c8d449df97f2c3a5c3dfb850546a6c85bbdf1
USEER2:$product$*2*6000*222*119ed5e1fb0b6d0d6a33fef33f60b9b5a17658b74f*9c931174620ab46648f5fd058a661b261508222e1*9f0c71256507e109b48*c13db2276c3fb2b2f6aa030e37fcac6fe2ce759c3df11e50d*b6ce0dc7864560c4e5bb90957866ebea96cd80bf9aa5c82d7c
USEEER_3:$product$*2*6000*222*996bc29ae7339249dc8c6994f7b15569da50497ddb03725693*f8752e68f7312f0b75226d22304440adca4b957f340fc87d6fe7a*439e268552abadf*d56c46fd11afa11324518d37bff8049750c4d51ae538726*0d7e7006e8bdcc9367293a062be7915a5620dcfdb9911
```

But I just wanna filter from $product$ to the end of line. So, result should be like that:

```
$product$*2*6000*222*bba98bfcb2b21dddde5d0656fc9221a0494b4fe70745107211e52*1b2a942fe069da12a226e3532dbc*c99c46a2c81b4c05cb3137ab30382394*31e7b8f7014160915ca98ce852e112e0123e6adc65ca4f083*4a722d4c8d449df97f2c3a5c3dfb850546a6c85bbdf1  
$product$*2*6000*222*119ed5e1fb0b6d0d6a33fef33f60b9b5a17658b74f*9c931174620ab46648f5fd058a661b261508222e1*9f0c71256507e109b48*c13db2276c3fb2b2f6aa030e37fcac6fe2ce759c3df11e50d*b6ce0dc7864560c4e5bb90957866ebea96cd80bf9aa5c82d7c
$product$*2*6000*222*996bc29ae7339249dc8c6994f7b15569da50497ddb03725693*f8752e68f7312f0b75226d22304440adca4b957f340fc87d6fe7a*439e268552abadf*d56c46fd11afa11324518d37bff8049750c4d51ae538726*0d7e7006e8bdcc9367293a062be7915a5620dcfdb9911
```

I'll trying with grep:

```
grep "\$product$". File.txt
```

But just selected **$product$**

Thanks. It's not important if the solution It's with Python, ReGex in grep, Javascript, not matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it in Javascript and Python: `(\$product.*$)`

- `\$` matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
- `product` matches the characters product literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

See: https://regex101.com/r/XzEqG3/1

Comment: Ohhhh, yes... This is the answer. Can you explain me a little bit about that please?. PD: I'll marked your answer as correctly, just we need wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Edited my answer. If it solves your problem, thanks for upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also don't even need a regex. You can use str.split instead:

`64403232_test.py`

```
USER_PRODUCTS = [
    "USEEER1:$product$*2*6000*222*bba98bfcb2b21dddde5d0656fc9221a0494b4fe70745107211e52*1b2a942fe069da12a226e3532dbc*c99c46a2c81b4c05cb3137ab30382394*31e7b8f7014160915ca98ce852e112e0123e6adc65ca4f083*4a722d4c8d449df97f2c3a5c3dfb850546a6c85bbdf1",
    "USEER2:$product$*2*6000*222*119ed5e1fb0b6d0d6a33fef33f60b9b5a17658b74f*9c931174620ab46648f5fd058a661b261508222e1*9f0c71256507e109b48*c13db2276c3fb2b2f6aa030e37fcac6fe2ce759c3df11e50d*b6ce0dc7864560c4e5bb90957866ebea96cd80bf9aa5c82d7c",
    "USEEER_3:$product$*2*6000*222*996bc29ae7339249dc8c6994f7b15569da50497ddb03725693*f8752e68f7312f0b75226d22304440adca4b957f340fc87d6fe7a*439e268552abadf*d56c46fd11afa11324518d37bff8049750c4d51ae538726*0d7e7006e8bdcc9367293a062be7915a5620dcfdb9911",
]

def get_product(product_str):
    return product_str.split(":")[1]

for user_product in USER_PRODUCTS:
    print(get_product(user_product))
```

Output of `python 64403232_test.py`

you get

```
$product$*2*6000*222*bba98bfcb2b21dddde5d0656fc9221a0494b4fe70745107211e52*1b2a942fe069da12a226e3532dbc*c99c46a2c81b4c05cb3137ab30382394*31e7b8f7014160915ca98ce852e112e0123e6adc65ca4f083*4a722d4c8d449df97f2c3a5c3dfb850546a6c85bbdf1
$product$*2*6000*222*119ed5e1fb0b6d0d6a33fef33f60b9b5a17658b74f*9c931174620ab46648f5fd058a661b261508222e1*9f0c71256507e109b48*c13db2276c3fb2b2f6aa030e37fcac6fe2ce759c3df11e50d*b6ce0dc7864560c4e5bb90957866ebea96cd80bf9aa5c82d7c
$product$*2*6000*222*996bc29ae7339249dc8c6994f7b15569da50497ddb03725693*f8752e68f7312f0b75226d22304440adca4b957f340fc87d6fe7a*439e268552abadf*d56c46fd11afa11324518d37bff8049750c4d51ae538726*0d7e7006e8bdcc9367293a062be7915a5620dcfdb9911
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. Add a loop if you want to do it for all lines.

```
import re

pobj = re.compile("\$product\$(.*)$", re.M)

mobj = pobj.search(your_str)
mobj.group()
```